# Redirect ajax content to the parent page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, redirect

On a webpage I have some content loaded via Ajax. If a user happens to visit the actual page that the ajax content is loaded from I want them to be redirected to the parent page itself. I thought I was being clever with the follow javascript, which works but seems dodgy and might break with a certain url:

```
$url = top.location.href;

if($url.indexOf('/events/') <= 0){
    window.location = site_url + "events/?event=" + id;
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? If this is possible in PHP this would be preferable.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you posting to get the "ajax contents"? If so, check if they aren't posting to redirect.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand. The content is loaded with jQuery's load() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

events.php

```
<?php

if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
    header("Location: index.html");
    exit;
}
echo "There are no events to display.";

?>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Events</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <script>
            $('.test').load('events.php');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

A different approach might be like:

events.php

```
<?php

if (!isset($_GET['a'])) {
    header("Location: index.html");
    exit;
}
echo "There are no events to display.";

?>
```

Then you can request with `$('.test').load('events.php?a');`.

Note that the user is always able to see the events no matter what you do, if the javascript can do it, they can too.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: reqUrl,
    data: reqBody,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
        if (data.redirect) {
            // data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
            window.location.href = data.redirect;
        }
        else {
             // data.form contains the HTML for the replacement form
            $("#myform").replaceWith(data.form);
        }
    }
});
```